# Template specialization with static char* array member, instanciation in multiple units

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, static

I have a templated struct to store a `static char*` array, like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct EnumStrings {
    static const char* const data[];
};
```

And I would like to specialize it this way:

```
template<> const char* const EnumStrings<SomeType>::data[] =
    {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};
```

If I place this instantiation in a header file, and this header file is included in multiple units, I get this linker error:

```
multiple definition of `EnumStrings<SomeType>::data'
```

Now, if I place this instantiation in the cpp file, other code using the `data` array cannot deduce its size with the `sizeof` operator, leading to the following error:

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘const char* const []’
```

Because I need to be able to iterate over this array, so, I am stuck... Any suggestion? Of course, I would like not to have to specify the size of the array somewhere, but maybe that's the only possibility.

Comment: Perhaps consider using an `std::array` with a static member function instead?

Comment: I have implemented to exactly same behaviour. However my implementation used a well defined interface like this: `std::string ToString(const T& enumValue);`. Under two `std::map`s were used resembling a "two way map". By splitting up the common code and the code to specialize in two separate classes (`Ènum<T>` and `EnumImpl<T>`), one didnt have to copy paste the common code (`std::map`, look up etc.; another very important reason for this was lazy initialization, as the using system of these classes is very complicated regarding to init), but just had to specialize `EnumImpl<T>::Initialize()`

Comment: Of course my approach is a bit slower (as `std::map` is not static). However my use case wasnt runtime relevant, so this was not a big problem and I prefered clean code over speed in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the struct declaration and definition of the data array specialization in an anonymous namespace. Struct will then have internal linkage which should prevent multiple definition errors.

```
namespace {
template<typename T>
struct EnumStrings {
    static const char* const data[];
};
template<> const char* const EnumStrings<int>::data[] =
    {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this changes anything, if instantiated in multiple units? I am still getting the first error I mentioned: `multiple definition of 'EnumStrings<SomeType>::data'`

Comment: @OlivierB The idea is that the template dont have external linkage, so this should prevent multiple definition errors. (`EnumStrings<Foo>` and `EnumStrings<Foo>` are different classes if compiled in different compilation units).

Comment: I tested this setup with struct in a.h, and a.cpp and b.cpp including it, and anonymous namespace prevents multiple definitions error as expected. Without anonymous namespace compiler emits the error you mention.

Comment: It works! I choose this answer because it turns out that @Constructors's answer does not work on Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

in C++11 following works:

```
// In header:

class SomeType;
template<typename T> struct EnumStrings;

template<>
struct EnumStrings<SomeType> {
    static constexpr
    const char* const data[] =
        {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};
};

// in cpp, if address of data is taken.

constexpr
const char* const EnumStrings<SomeType>::data[];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should divide declaration and definition of `data` array specialization. Put this in your header file:

```
template<typename T>
struct EnumStrings {
    static const char* const data[];
};

// declaration of `data` array specialization
template<> const char* const EnumStrings<SomeType>::data[4];
```

And this in your `cpp` file:

```
// definition of `data` array specialization
template<> const char* const EnumStrings<SomeType>::data[] =
    {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work, because I need to know the size of `data` in other units. This leads to the second error I mentioned:

    `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘const char* const []’`

Comment: @OlivierB Simply add the size of the array in `*.h` file. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Mmh, with this, I am still getting `multiple definition of 'EnumStrings<SomeType>::data'` error... I don't really understand why?

Comment: @OlivierB What compiler do you use?

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

Comment: @OlivierB It is very strange because this code works fine compiled with my g++ 4.6.1.

Comment: @OlivierB I know that there is a problem with declaration of fully specialized member of class template in Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, but gcc...

Comment: @OlivierB Are you sure that you put the definition of `data` array specialization in only one file?

Comment: Never mind, some dependencies were not recompiled. It works. Actually, I think your solution is perfectly fine, adding the array size in the .h file is ok, as if it doesn't match the definition, it won't compile, so it's garanteed to be consistent...

Comment: @OlivierB Good. But don't forget that it will compile even if the size of array in `*.h` file is greater the count of array elements in `*.cpp` file.